# Trying a query using an int and a string

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not having a lot of luck figuring out how to query with an int and a string.  I have found examples with two ints and I have found examples with two strings.  I have tried different combinations and nothing seems to work.  Below are two examples of what I have tried and have not worked.  What am I doing wrong.  I have used both inpspection_id and item_name on there own and they both work.

Try 1:

```
public int getId(int inspection_id ,String item_name)throws Exception
{
    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_INSPECTION_ID, KEY_ITEM_NAME},
            "inspection_id=" + inspection_id +"item_name='"+ item_name + "'", null, null, null, null);
    int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String result=c.getString(id);
    int primId=Integer.parseInt(result);
    c.close();
    return primId;

}
```

Try 2:

```
public int getId(int inspection_id ,String item_name)throws Exception
{
    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_INSPECTION_ID, KEY_ITEM_NAME},
            "inspection_id=" + inspection_id +"AND KEY_ITEM_NAME = ?", new String[]{item_name}, null, null, null);
    int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String result=c.getString(id);
    int primId=Integer.parseInt(result);
    c.close();
    return primId;

}
```

Try 3:

```
public int getId(int inspection_id ,String item_name)throws Exception
{
    String s_id= Integer.toString(inspection_id);
    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_INSPECTION_ID, KEY_ITEM_NAME},
            "KEY_INSPECTION_ID = ? AND KEY_ITEM_NAME = ?",
             new String[] {  s_id, item_name }, null, null, null);
    int id=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String result=c.getString(id);
    int primId=Integer.parseInt(result);
    c.close();
    return primId;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way, with single quotes for the int ones.

```
"inspection_id='" + inspection_id +"'item_name='"+ item_name + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks it turned out to be something else, but when I changed it the comment worked